# Update html files in android app

Tags: android, html, eclipse, download, assets

I want to add some HTML files in my program that can be update later.
I want to add these files in assets folder but I can't rewrite files when downloaded.(eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

The assets folder is inside of you package - obviously you can't edit that.

Download such updates to your applications data directory. You'd then have to check in code if there is a file in the data directory, and if not use the one in assets.